# How to get which UITableViewCell selected without using UITableViewDelegate methods in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I want to know that how to get selected cell's row index on selection of cell. But how to do it without using`UITableViewDelegate` methods.
Please tell me.
I have search lot but not getting solution so please if anyone know tell me.
Please shared the viewpoints regarding it.

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: No i have done search on the link which you have mentioned

Comment: What is the reason, that you dont wish to use the delegates? That is the easiest way. Your intention might help us to give you a better solution.

Comment: Actually this question is ask by one of interviewer  to me

Comment: Answered... Hope it is explanative and helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

In that case, your interviewer wanted to know how can you implement the delegation yourself...

To achieve that, Create a custom class "YourTableViewCell" extended from`UITableViewCell` and use this class object to be returned in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Write a protocol "`CellSelectionProtocol`" with a method -

```
-(void) cellSelected: (YourTableViewCell *) cell;
```

Now delegate this protocol to your ViewController that has your TableView
and define the implementation of the method as below -

```
-(void) cellSelected: (YourTableViewCell *) cell
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [_yourTableView indexPathForCell: cell];
}
```

My answer would be this if it was an interview, and I am pretty sure it would be accepted.

But for a good architecture... the protocol & delegate implementation should be in two levels, like ->

YourTableViewCell -> *delegates* **-cellSelected:** -> YourTableView -> *delegates* **`-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`** -> YourViewController

**Please see:** Your interviewer just wanted to know how you create delegations manually, instead of using default UITableViewDelegates.

**EDIT** @ Unheilig

I mean in 2 levels because, the selection of a `UITableViewCell` has to be delegated to the `UITableView` and not directly to the controller for the following reasons

- `UITableViewCell` is subview of `UITableView`
- There can be multiple `UITableView` in a controller. So if you delegate cell selection directly, how will you tell the controller that cell got selected for which `UITableView` object?
- Also `UITableView` might have to do other processing with other `UITableViewCell`, Like if selected and changes backgroundColor, the previous selected should get deselected and get default backgroundColor. Or add to the array of selected cells, if multiple selection is enabled.

There are many such similar architectural necessities that make me say - "But for a good architecture... the protocol & delegate implementation should be in two levels, like ->"

I hope that is pretty explanative now...

Comment: Thanks Mayer... i think it is the answer he expecting from me.

Comment: Can you please give me code form doing custom delegate for UITableView.

Comment: Check this out for better explanation and implementation...
There are better experts than me to explain to the core...
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Also check documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: i have ready seen these links but i want to know for UITableView how to do that. please give me some code for delegate for tableview

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh Could you please elaborate / explain further a bit on "_But for a good architecture... the protocol & delegate implementation should be in two levels_"? What do you mean by two levels?

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh i have accepted your answer and also upvooted can you do same for me.

Comment: @ Unheilig : I have elaborated for you. Hope this explains my statement

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to get selected cell row index with out using tableview delegate methods.

when you click on tableview, didSelectRowAtIndexPath called and get the tableview cell index.

There is one way to do this, but it is not correct procedure to get tableview cell index. Create a button on tableviewcell and pass the indexvalue as sender tag to button action. But need to click only on that button.

Answer edited:

---

Create a transparent button on tableview cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and pass the cell index to button tag.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell addSubview:button];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[sender tag]);
}
```

---

Comment: This question is interview question. one of interviewer ask that question to me.

Comment: Ok. As per my knowledge, there is no way. Try to create transparent button on UITableviewCell. Pass the index value to button action from cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: but if there are 1000 of cell that how to do that...??

Comment: Create a button in cellForRowIndexPath method. For every cell this method called. Give me sometime, I will check and let you know.

Comment: k. try it and let me know

Comment: Answered.. Check the code..but strictly speaking it is bad process

Comment: The motive of this question was always pointing to custom Protocols and delegates.